# Unity Playerprefs Loading if update app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, save, load

I'm a bit new to Unity, so can someone help?

I have my app, but its not released, its just in developement build, and i have a question, that `Playerprefs` doesnt load if i update the app (I changed the version number.), how can i do that, that if i update the app then PlayerPrefs does load, and not create a new "game".

Can someone explain this?

It works well, but its only doesnt load when i update the game.

Comment: On Android, `SharedPreferences` (via which PlayerPrefs are persisted) are stored by packagename and not version... So updating the installed APK *should* be able to see the previous version's SharedPreferences as well.

Comment: So just as for regular Android apps, incrementing the `versionCode` won't make the previous versions' SharedPreferences invisible or unseeable. I'd suggest checking your packagename and making sure nothing besides the versionCode is changed/incremented

Comment: You are really updating the app, from Android, aren't you? That is, are you sure about not unistalling the app before installing the new version? Because, as far as I know, PlayerPrefs are deleted only by unistalling the app.

Comment: Yeah, i think its working now..

Comment: @Kalip: What have you tried, to make it work?

Comment: @Andrea setup the keystore thing.